# Terraform Escape Single Quotes

Tags: terraform

I am trying to escape single quotes in my terraform script and inventory file.

Terraform script line:

```
list_compute= "${join("\n",formatlist("%s openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"", "${module.compute.ops_compute_names}"))}"
```

How do I preserve/escape the single quote around region, primary, zone and east?

Also my template file which is used for rendering:

```
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]
```

How do I preserve/escape the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
join("\n",formatlist("%s openshift_node_labels={'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}", "${module.compute.ops_compute_names}"))
```

As long as `ops_compute_names` is a list

Comment: I tried that but terraform still strips off the single quotes

Comment: After adding \, still getting errors:  https://gist.github.com/infinitydon/e5132c9a1707cc5710cb5b1f867ad6e9

Comment: Please any ides why an getting illegal character escape:

list_node= "${join("\n",formatlist("%s openshift_node_labels=\"{\'region\': \'infra\', \'zone\': \'default\'}\", "${module.compute.ops_infra_names}"))}"
Error running fmt: At 105:144: illegal char escape

Comment: see the edit to the answer